# Intent data with scheme

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending a broadcast from App a to App b. How do I fill in the intent in App a to that App b will be able to extract the packageName using the following:

```
intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart();
```

I am aware that it is possible to pass data using extras but I do not control the code in App b.

Comment: If app b is not the system app like galery, message...and you don't control the code in app b => how can you get anything from a?

Comment: The code in app b is already in production. That's why I cannot change it.